# How to add my required .dll files into my C++ executable?

Tags: c++, dll, compilation, embed

Im new to C++ and I am using the [cpp-httlib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) library to make requests to specific websites.
Now in order for the library to work I need to have libcrypto and libssl as a dll inside the same path where my executable file is in order for it to work.

I only want 1 executable file. How can I embed those dlls or make it work without them?

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Your easiest route would be to create an installer package like most commercial software does. I use NSIS for this but there are many other options. The other option is to statically link. Embedding the dlls would likely require you to have to extract them in some temporary folder and running from there.

Comment: Hmm yeah... I used to code in C# and there I could just install Costura Fody which automatically embeds all the dlls into the executable when I build it. Wish there would be something like this for C++ but can't find anything...